# IF/Else and Goto issues

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've been struggling with trying to put together this batch script to check a process (it can be any process). count the number of instances of it are running and save the output of that count. If its not running (a count of 0) then its fine but if it is running (1 or greater) but is under say '5' in this case have it echo a statement.

every time i try to do this i either get 'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file or when the script gets to the goto :problem it seems to completely ignore the else statement.

```
@echo off

for /f %%g in (' tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" ^| find /I /C "chrome.exe" ') do (

if %%g EQU 0 goto :notrunning
if %%g GTR 0 goto :problem
)


:notrunning
echo Program is not running
pause

:problem
If %%g LSS 5 ( echo problem
) else ( echo chrome is fine
)
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `goto` breaks the `for` context. Try this:

```
@echo off
for /f %%g in (' tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" ^| find /I /C "chrome.exe" ') do set status=%%g

if %status% EQU 0 goto :notrunning
if %status% GTR 0 goto :problem

:notrunning
echo Program is not running
pause

:problem
If %status% LSS 5 ( echo problem
) else ( echo chrome is fine
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid the **else** statement in the **if** command. It may not be supported in the version of windows you are using. Try to get rid of the **else** statement and have multiple **if** statements. Here, try this:

```
@echo off

for /f %%g in (' tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq chrome.exe" ^| find /I /C "chrome.exe" ') do (

if %%g EQU 0 goto :notrunning
if %%g GTR 0 goto :problem
)


:notrunning
echo Program is not running
pause

:problem
If %%g LSS 5 echo problem
If %%g GTR 4 echo chrome is fine
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

`%%g` is out-of-scope when you reach the label `:problem`

you need

```
if %%g GTR 0 set /a somevar=%%g&goto :problem
```

...

```
:problem
If %somevar% LSS 5 ( echo problem
) else ( echo chrome is fine
)
```